# Using Library Project in Eclipse, not updating latest changes

Tags: eclipse, android-library

An  very annoying thing. Here is my setup:
- Latest version of Eclipse
- 1 Android project which is Library
- 1 Android project which has the library project added

I make a lot of changes on the library project, but most of the time, when I run the project on my phone, the latest changes aren't updated. Let's say for example, I run the app, I make a small change in library, run the final project and it says

> "Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front"

I press Run again and now it loads fine with the changes. So basically, I need to press the Run button for 2 or 3 times to have the latest changes. Also, sometimes it starts in Debug mode, even if I press Run.

Anyone can explain me how to correct this behavior ?
Is there a way to force a Clean App Projects, before Run ?

Comment: Look at this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/13560368/779408

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're extending project is running from the compiled .jar file in your Shared Projects bin directory. If you project is called `SharedProject` you'll have a `bin/SharedProject.jar`.

One of the "bugs"* in the Eclipse Android Shared Project setup is that when you clean and build your extending project it doesn't also clean and build your shared projects.

Simply clean your shared project to have it refresh the jar and then clean your extending project.

*-*I think this is actually "as designed" as cleaning and building 10 shared libraries would take an age if you actually only want to clean and build your extending project.**