# Changes to Android library project are not applied until restarting Eclipse

Tags: android, compilation, android-library, library-project

I have a main Android application that is using an Android library project. When I change my library project and `Build Project` or `Build All` the changes are not detected in main project until I clean the main project or close and reopen Eclipse.

How con I solve this problem? Is there any rapid solution?

**Update**

I am using:

Eclipse 3.7.1

Android SDK API 15 Rev 3

Android SDK Tools Rev 19

Android SDK Platform-tools Rev 11

Comment: What version of Eclipse? Version of Android SDK tools? What platform (OS)? Do you have "Build Automatically" enabled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution 1)** I clicked on **Android Dependencies** in **Package Explorer** and pressed **F5** (refresh) and built the main project and problem solved.

[image]

**Solution 2)** [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12875910/779408) also works for this problem. It says you can add the project to the build path. ( Right click on project -> properties -> java build path -> Projects -> Add).

Under the **Order and Export** section, make sure the library is above the **Android Dependencies**.